# Qual é a vantagem de utilizar Interface em C#?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Existe um cenário específico para utilização de Interfaces ? Se sim, como posso saber quando utilizar?

Sempre tive vontade de utilizar nos projetos que venho criando, porém nunca sei o momento adequado.

Sei que ela garante que todos os métodos declarados nela, tenham que ser implementados nas classes que tem a assinatura dessa interface.

Comment: @bigown, Não tinha visto que já existia uma pergunta parecida com a minha vou ler a mesma e ver se é o que procuro. Obrigado

Comment: Particularmente tenho orgulho da resposta que dei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160052/qual-%c3%a9-a-vantagem-de-se-usar-uma-interface-se-eu-sempre-consigo-o-mesmo-comporta/160060#160060 :-)