# Qual é a vantagem de se usar uma interface se eu sempre consigo o mesmo comportamento usando simples classes no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, orientação-a-objetos, interface

**Antes de mais nada, quero salientar que esta questão NÃO TRATA de comparação entre classes abstratas e interfaces, ela visa descobrir se há alguma vantagem na utilização de interfaces em detrimento da utilização de classes ordinárias e conceitos básicos de OO. A informação acerca de pergunta em duplicidade não se aplica**

Segue o texto da pergunta:

As interfaces sempre foram um assunto um tanto obscuro para mim. Eu simplesmente não consigo achar utilidade para elas no meu dia a dia, mesmo com tantas pessoas dizendo que elas são um recurso poderoso. Tudo que eu faço com interfaces eu consigo fazer com simples herança de classes.

Juntamente com a resposta, seria interessante que alguém propusesse aqui algum problema PRÁTICO que só se resolve com o uso de interfaces. Por favor, que não seja algum problema relacionado às tecnologia COM/COM+ que obrigam as interfaces "simplesmente porque sim". O melhor exemplo seria algo simples, usando classes reais e uma explicação do porquê o problema só se resolve usando as interfaces, ou no mínimo, se resolve melhor usando elas.

Quero lembrar que a resposta deve levar em conta que se está usando o Delphi para implementar, porque o Delphi pode possuir classes com métodos virtuais e abstratos que não são interfaces, mas se comportam como tal.

Comment: @DanielOmine não acho que seja duplicata. Essa pergunta aqui é muito mais específica. A outra é completamente genérica (e ampla demais), já que quem perguntou não especificou nenhum parâmetro para suas dúvidas. O outro não sabe a diferença entre classe e interface. Aqui se pergunta qual a vantagem de interfaces se é possível realizar "tudo" com herança de classes.

Comment: @DanielOmine por gentileza, se isso for possível, desmarque minha questão como duplicada. Eu já a editei para esclarecer que não se trata de comparação entre Interfaces e classes abstratas. Acho que remover essa indicação de duplicata vai ajudar outras pessoas que, como eu, tem a mesma dúvida. Seguir o link indicado no texto da duplicata só vai atrapalhar o entendimento. Obrigado!

Comment: Tal como o @Loudenvier disse, essa pergunta não é duplicata de nada, primeiramente porque o contexto não é genérico e em segundo lugar, eu quero saber é das vantagens (se é que existem) de se usar interfaces, porque eu já sei que uma classe abstrata mistura os conceitos de interface e classes ordinárias. Obrigado!

Comment: Desculpe Carlos, mas a questão é conceitual. Por isso é duplicata do link sugerido.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou simplesmente ignorar então, já que do meu ponto de vita (e de outros) ela não tem nada a ver com a outra a não ser o fato de citar classes e interfaces

Comment: @DanielOmine apenas por ser conceitual isso não faz dessa pergunta uma duplicata da outra. Acho que foram rígidos demais nessa marcação. Contudo, acho interessante também que quem veja essa pergunta possa acessar a outra, muito mais ampla e genérica, para entender os conceitos de classes e interface em si, e não as vantagens de um e de outro em contextos específicos. Também sugiro ao "perguntador" que se acostume a ter suas perguntas e respostas sob o escrutínio de outros e não levar para o lado pessoal! Stack Overflow é revolucionário e funciona muito bem!!!

Comment: Faça um tour para entender melhor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: As questões podem ser diferentes mas as respostas são "iguais".

Comment: A resposta dada aqui poderia ter sido dada lá. As respostas lá respondem o que foi perguntado aqui. Então é duplicata de acordo com a definição de duplicata que usamos. A pergunta não precisa ser exatamente igual para ser considerada duplicata.

Comment: @Loudenvier só esclarecendo, não levei para o lado pessoal, só não vou aceitar algo que não faz sentido algum. Na minha santa estupidez, eu não vejo qualquer relação entre a suposta duplicata e minha pergunta a não ser o fato de ambas envolverem classes e interfaces. Eu não queria saber a diferença entre uma classe com métodos abstratos e uma interface. Isso eu aprendi no "pré". Eu queria mesmo era entender qual a utilidade de uma interface quando eu vivi até hoje sem nunca tê-las de fato usado e você deu a explicação que eu precisava. Mission Accomplished

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nem tudo que se faz com interfaces, é possível de ser feito com classes. Uma interface é um contrato, não implica qualquer implementação, já uma classe implica uma implementação, ainda que tenha possibilidade de se usar métodos abstrados e virtuais. Uma interface, portanto, pode ser *implementada* por qualquer classe, em qualquer hierarquia de classes. Já usar apenas classes implicaria que absolutamente TODOS os objetos envolvidos em alguma operação, necessariamente teriam que pertencer à mesma hierarquia de classe.

Geralmente falando:

- **Herança** implica uma relação "**ser**" (Funcionário **é** uma Pessoa)
- **Interface** implica uma relação "**pode**" (Bitmap **pode** ser desalocado)

Vou responder sem código de implementação (e talvez com uma sintaxe não 100%) para evitar limitar essa resposta ao Delphi, já que sua pergunta é de uso geral para Orientação ao Objeto.

Imagine que você queira implementar uma forma padronizada para serialização de classes para JSON (ou outro formato qualquer). Se você escolher o caminho da herança terá que, obrigatoriamente, forçar que todos os objetos herdem de um mesmo pai. Isso pode ser indesejável, pois introduzirá um acoplamento entre classes com nenhuma relação entre si. Sua hierarquia de objetos deixará de ser *pura*, podemos dizer.

Com classes você teria que ter algo assim:

```
TSuperClassePaiDeTodos : class
published
    function Serializa : String; virtual; abstract;
end;

TUsuario : class(TSuperClassePaiDeTodos) 
published
    function Serializa : String; override;
end;

TLancamentoFiscal : class(TSuperClassePaiDeTodos)
published
    function Serializa : String; override;
end;

TOperadorMatematico : class(TSuperClassePaiDeTodos)
published
    function Serializa : String; override;
end;
```

Não existe nenhuma relação entre um Lançamento Fiscal e um Usuário (muito menos um operador matemático que você usa, por exemplo, para interpretar expressões dinâmicas criadas pelo usuário), mas usar herança de classes para forçar "um contrato" (ou uma interface), nesse caso nos obrigou a criar uma relação entre essas classes: todas herdam da mesma classe pai e exigem a implementação do método Serializa.

Isso não seria tão grave, uma vez que queremos que todas sejam serializáveis. Mas e se precisarmos de algum comportamento que seja comum entre algumas classes, mas não em outras (imagine que você tenha centenas de classes, divididas em várias hierarquias, todas herdando da classe pai). O que você faria nesse caso? Você iria lá na classe "pai de todos" e adicionaria um método abstrato. O efeito cascata disso é enorme: **todas as suas centenas de classes teriam que implementar esse novo método**, mesmo aquelas que não precisam dele.

Imagine que queiramos adicionar, por exemplo, funcionalidade de auditoria, que é comum à vários objetos, mas não todos. Por exemplo, faz sentido um Usuário e um Lançamento Contábil serem auditados, mas nunca um Operador Matemático. Como resolver isso de forma elegante?

Você poderia simplesmente fazer uma implementação vazia do método da auditoria, mas isso já começa a soar como uma gambiarra. E ainda pode ter efeitos não esperados se o código que chama o método de auditoria está esperando algum comportamento específico de quem implementa esse contrato/interface/função, como, por exemplo, atualizar algum contador, alocar alguma área de memória, etc. Você acaba tendo um objeto que **implementa** o método de auditoria na teoria, mas não de fato. Soa mal, não?

Você poderia tentar modificar a hierarquia de classes para descobrir uma forma de colocar um pai comum somente entre as classes que precisem de auditoria. Isso ainda é fácil com apenas três classes:

```
TSuperClassePaiDeTodos : class
published
    function Serializa : String; virtual; abstract;
end;

TSofreAuditoria : clas(TSuperClassePaiDeTodos)
published
    procedure Audita: virtual; abstract;
end;

TUsuario : class(TSofreAuditoria)
published
    function Serializa : String; override;
    procedure Audita: override;
end;

TLancamentoFiscal : class(TSofreAuditoria)
published
    function Serializa : String; override;
    procedure Audita: override;
end;

TOperadorMatematico : class(TSuperClassePaiDeTodos)
published
    function Serializa : String; override;
end;
```

Agora, com uma dezena de classes isso se torna um processo extremamente confuso, com uma centena de classes é inviável. Além disso sua hierarquia de classes já começa a ficar esquisita, difícil de compreender. Em um determinado momento, você perderá o controle.

*E tudo isso porque você está tentando substituir a funcionalidade das Interfaces por uma hierarquia de classes.*

Com interfaces você pode **garantir** que objetos tenham algum, ou alguns métodos em comum, ou seja, sigam um contrato, sem forçar que esses objetos pertençam a uma mesma hierarquia de classes predefinida. Com interfaces você define capacidades que podem ser implementadas por diversas classes não correlacionadas.

O problema que usamos de exemplo pode ser resolvido de forma simples:

```
ISerializavel : Interface(IInterface)
published
    function Serializa : String; 
end;

IAuditavel : Interface(IInterface)
published
    procedure Audita;
end;

TUsuario : class(TInterfacedObject, ISerializavel, IAuditavel)
published
    function Serializa : String; 
    procedure Audita;
end;

TLancamentoFiscal : class(TInterfacedObject, ISerializavel, IAuditavel)
published
    function Serializa : String; 
    procedure Audita;
end;

TOperadorMatematico : class(TInterfacedObject, ISerializavel)
published
    function Serializa : String; 
end;
```

Note que removemos toda e qualquer relação indesejável entre as classes. A hierarquia não mais precisa seguir uma definição rígida. E a introdução da funcionalidade de auditoria não exigiu mudanças na hierarquia, nem sua implementação em objetos que não são auditáveis. O Código ficou também bastante mais legível e manutenível.

Como uma classe pode implementar mais de uma interface, isso se torna uma forma muito eficiente de organizar funcionalidades que sejam comuns entre objetos que não tenham relação entre si, ou seja, que não tenham uma relação "**ser**" entre si. Mantenha sua hierarquia de classes fortemente cimentada nos conceitos de orientação ao objeto: se um objeto não é, de verdade, da mesma família de outro, não faça deles irmãos, ou pais e filhos! Use agregação ou interfaces.

**Vantagens, desvantagens e aplicações**

Interfaces são uma forma de especificar um contrato (uma forma padronizada e esperada de interagir com algum objeto), mas classes também definem contratos. É um mito que interfaces sejam obrigatórias para se especificar um contrato, como já vimos, classes podem definir métodos abstratos, os quais precisam, necessariamente, ser implementados nos descendentes. Isso firma um contrato.

Na minha opinião devemos optar primeiro por classes, uma vez que são mais fáceis de manter do que interfaces. Apenas quando surgirem necessidades que sejam melhor atendidas por interfaces (como o exemplo aqui usado) é que introduziria interfaces. Muitas vezes, ao introduzir interfaces, crio uma classe pai/mãe que fornece uma implementação padrão para tal interface a fim de facilitar sua implementação (mas isso não força que todas as classes que implementem tal interface herdem também dessa classe: elas podem implementar a interface do zero).

O livro [.NET Design Framework Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816563/when-should-i-choose-inheritance-over-an-interface-when-designing-c-sharp-class) concorda com meu posicionamento e fornece mais alguns argumentos sobre o favorecimento do uso de classes no lugar de interfaces:

> Em geral classes são a construção preferida para expor abstrações.
>
> A principal desvantagem de interfaces é que elas são muito menos
>   flexíveis do que classes no que concerne a futura evolução de uma API.
>   Uma vez que você publique uma interface, seu conjunto de membros está
>   congelado para sempre. Quaisquer adições à interface quebrariam tipos
>   existentes que implementem aquela interface.
>
> Uma classe nos dá mais flexibilidade. Você pode adicionar membros à
>   classes que você já publicou. Desde que o método não seja abstrato (ou
>   seja, desde que você forneça uma implementação padrão para o método),
>   quaisquer classes derivadas continuarão funcionando sem modificações.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> Um dos argumentos mais comuns em favor de interfaces é que elas
>   permitem separar contrato de implementação. Contudo, o argumento
>   assume incorretamente que você não possa separar contratos de
>   implementação usando classes. Classes abstratas residindo em um
>   assembly (uma Unit, biblioteca ou um componente em Delphi) separado de
>   suas implementações concretas é uma ótima forma de alcançar tal
>   separação.

*Nota: tradução livre feita por mim!*

O problema da evolução de APIs pode ser visto na bagunça generalizada que são as APIs de Direct X. Você tem um monte de interfaces, com o mesmo nome, seguidas de um número apenas porque as interfaces já publicadas não poderiam ser modificadas com as novas funcionalidades introduzidas à cada versão do Direct X. Agora temos IDirect3D7, IDirect3D8, IDirect3D9, etc.

No caso do Direct X, como as interfaces precisam ser usadas por diferentes linguagens de programação, seria muito difícil publicar essa funcionalidade sem recorrer ao uso de interfaces, mas esse mesmo problema pode acontecer numa API nossa se não tomarmos cuidado de usar classes onde classes são mais pertinentes do que interfaces!

Portanto, use interfaces quando são a ferramenta correta para o caso. Toda vez que você tiver um contrato que se aplique a classes totalmente independentes (não correlatas) as interfaces serão a melhor solução para o caso, evitando que você engesse sua hierarquia de classes forçando heranças artificiais.

Use interfaces também quando precisar implementar herança múltipla (ou algo similar) em linguagens que não forneçam suporte para tal.

Use, também, interfaces quando a imutabilidade for um efeito desejado: você não quer que aquele contrato possa ser modificado no futuro, e sim que um novo contrato precise ser firmado (uma nova interface introduzida) em caso de surgir novas funcionalidades.

Evite, à todo custo, a generalização prematura, pois isso é, tal qual a otimização prematura, uma perda de tempo na maioria das vezes. Projete bem sua estrutura de objetos, mas apenas generalize quando perceber a real necessidade. Lembre-se que é possível (e desejável) introduzir generalizações durante refatoramentos, e isso, inclusive é o indicado nos paradigmas Agile, XP, enfim, os mais modernos.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, segue o link do blog do Marcos Douglas.
As conclusões dele em relação ao padrões costuma ser totalmente diferente das que costumamos ver/ler, e nos faz perceber coisas que costumamos deixar passar. http://objectpascalprogramming.com/posts/interfaces-em-todo-lugar/

Comment: @VictorZanella interessante o link, porém discordo veementemente do amigo Marcos Douglas. Meu posicionamento é o de **nunca** usar interfaces, exceto quando são a melhor ferramenta para resolver determinado problema. Quando são funcionalidades ortogonais à sua hierarquia de classe (o exemplo que dei na resposta), ou quando se procura simular herança múltipla em linguagens que não suportem a funcionalidade. Existem outros pontos a se considerar também. Vou atualizar a resposta com esses pontos. Obrigado pelo link!

Comment: É bacana ver essas discordância, nos faz repensar nossos conceitos. Eu particularmente gosto das interfaces, e tento utiliza-las sempre que possível. Ela costuma evitar vários problemas. Mas é como você disse, cada um tem um posicionamento em relação a isso. valeu :D

Comment: @VictorZanella atualizei a resposta explicando minha visão de que interfaces devem ser usadas quando necessário e não sempre. Isso coaduna com a posição da equipe de desenvolvimento do .NET também. Quando se procura imutabilidade, sim, interfaces são ótimas formas de se implementar isso. Mas forçar imutabilidade em tudo é generalizar prematuramente seu código. No final pode terminar com um código difícil de manter e demorado para introduzir mudanças e nossa área é uma área onde mudança é o modus operandi! Abração.

Comment: @VictorZanella obrigado pela indicação do link, mas eu vou dispensar, porque eu conheço bem os tópicos do Marcos e normalmente discordo bastante deles. Os motivos são irrelevantes no momento, mas saiba que toda vez que eu vejo um artigo dele eu fico profundamente incomodado.

Comment: @Loudenvier, notei que sua resposta está bem longa e isso deve significar que ela contém o que eu preciso para que minha dúvida seja sanada. Junto isso ao fato de você discordar do Macos Douglas e acredito que desta vez vou entender tudo ou pelo menos chegar perto disso. Não vou poder ler agora, mas com certeza o farei e vou dar o feedback. Obrigado!

Comment: @Loudenvier Sua resposta foi excelente. Uma pena que tenham achado que esta questão poderia ser respondida como uma outra (que não tem nada a ver com ela). Espero que quem procurar a resposta para isso tenha paciência para ler seu texto, pois sem dúvida a resposta correta está nele. Quando você falou "Toda vez que você tiver um contrato que se aplique a classes totalmente independentes (não correlatas) as interfaces serão a melhor solução para o caso, evitando que você engesse sua hierarquia de classes forçando heranças artificiais." eu imediatamente identifiquei o meu problema

Comment: @Loudenvier meu problema é que estou modificando um componente que faz acesso a banco de dados usando para isso vários componentes de conexão (BDE, FireDAC, UniDAC, etc). Basicamente eu devo associar meu componente principal a um destes componentes de conexão, mas eles pertencem a classes distintas, sem um pai comum. A solução original foi usar interfaces para forçar a implementação de métodos comuns dentro do contexto de cada um destes componentes de conexão, ou seja, eu não ligo estes componentes diretamente ao componente principal, mas uso um outro componente, que eu chamo de conector

Comment: @Loudenvier Cada um destes conectores herda de uma classe comum, que possui métodos genéricos que podem ser usados dentro do contexto de qualquer componente de conexão (sem fazer referência direta a eles) ao mesmo tempo em que implementa uma interface que possui métodos inserir, excluir, alterar e selecionar, os quais PRECISAM ser implementados dentro do contexto de cada um dos componentes de conexão, ou seja, o método inserir da classe TFireDACConnector, por exemplo, vai usar exclusivamente o FireDAC para inserir no banco de dados

Comment: @Loudenvier Imagino então que dentro desta minha situação o uso de interfaces seja válido, mesmo quando eu vejo que poderia ter criado uma classe comum e herdado dela para cada um dos componentes de conexão. Pensando em "contrato" eu imagino então que eu realmente tenho classes completamente diferentes (cada um dos componentes de conexão possíveis) e por conta disso eu preciso manipular este comportamento distinto em implementações obrigatórias de métodos específicos. Gostaria muito de discutir mais esse assunto, mas acho que aqui não é o melhor lugar

Comment: @CarlosFeitozaFilho no seu caso eu usaria uma classe pai apenas! Com métodos abstratos. Eu vejo essas classes de conexão, todas elas, como relacionadas entre si. Não importa que usem (por agregação) uma objeto diferente para falar como banco de dados. Todas tem que implementar os métodos de conexão e os de inserção, exclusão, etc. Não é? Você pode até implementar um tratamento comum nesses métodos (por exemplo, pra chamar rotina de validação dos dados, testar conexão aberta, etc. tudo na classe base). Na classe filha apenas redireciona para o objeto correto de cada banco de dados.

Comment: @Loudenvier faz muito sentido isso sim, obrigado mais uma vez!